# php: create a socket_connect problems

Tags: php, sockets

I have an doubts, it's possible to create a socket_connect from a web server hosted in the web to my home network?

```
<?php

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

if(!socket_connect($sock , 'my ip of network i'm connected' , 80))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Connection established \n"; ?>
```

I hosted this code in a webserver and when I tested this it appears this error:

Socket created 
Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in ........./update_state.php on line 13
Could not connect: [111] Connection refused

Comment: when you say "my ip" are you using your public IP, or the private one like 192.168.x.x?

Comment: First, can you 'see' your 'pc' from the internet? This means you have to open ports on routers, set the router to 'forward' messages from and to particular 'ports' and 'internal' pc's. Allow the pc to be found on the internet. And finally run the appropraite server on your pc. And, yes, I do all of the above to get my pc, with a dynamic ip, available on the internet. search 'dynamic ip dns'. There is lots of assistance available

Comment: When I say "my ip" I use a public ip